# Mongoose grouping error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got a trouble to filter and group on mongodb. I really didn't undertanded how it works.

For example, in this query:

```
Room.aggregate(
[{
    "$where": { "roomId" : myIdHere },
    "$group": {
        "_id": '$mobileUser.genderType',
        "genderTypeCount": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}]
```

Room model:

```
var roomModelSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    roomId: String,
    mobileUser: {
        facebookId: String,
        email: String,
        name: String,
        photoUrl: String,
        genderType: String,
        birthday: Date,
        city: String    
    },
    insertDate: Date
})
```

What i should do to filter by roomId and group by genderType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) instead of `$where`, and put each pipeline operation into its own object:

```
Room.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "roomId" : myIdHere } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": '$mobileUser.genderType',
        "genderTypeCount": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }}
], function(err, result) {...})
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks man. I have a question, when you said 'pipeline' how can i compare this term with relational db? I'm getting crazy trying to understating it.

Comment: You can read about aggregation pipelines [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/#aggregation-pipelines).